# como usar corretamente o mysqli->prepare e o bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

como eu posso utilizar corretamente o `mysqli->prepare` com o `bind_param` estou tentando fazer um login de usuário utilizando essas duas funções porem me ocorre o seguinte erro

`Only variables should be passed by reference`
`mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given`

meu codigo

```
$sql = parent::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?");
            $sql->bind_param('ss',$this->getEmail(),$this->getSenha());
            $sql->execute();
            parent::desconectar();


            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                $aux = $sql->fetch_object();
                $_SESSION['idAdmin'] = $aux->id;
                $_SESSION['logadoAdmin'] = true;

                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
```